# Vector of typedef using c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using dlib to implement an algorithm, so far I was using a single kernel doing lake this:

The class in charge of the clustering:

```
template <
    typename kernel_type
    >
class kalog : public noncopyable
{
 public:
    kalog (
        const kernel_type& kernel_
    ):
       kernel(kernel_)
    {
    }
 private:
    kernel_type kernel;
}
```

The main:

```
typedef matrix<double,2,1> sample_type;
typedef radial_basis_kernel<sample_type> kernel_type;
kalog<kernel_type> my_kalog(kernel_type(0.1));
```

What I would like is to handle multiple kernel, but those ones could be different (radial_basis_kernel, polynomial_kernel, ...)

How, can I manage to provide my class a list of different type of kernel?
any idea?

Comment: It is either `kernel_type` or `kernel_type2`, both of which are the same.

Comment: Are you trying to `push_back` a type into a `vector`?

Comment: kernal_type is a type, not a variable.  Did you mean to use `std::vector<kernal_type> kernal_types` and `push_back` various kernal_types?

Answer (score 0):

Keep

```
typedef radial_basis_kernel<sample_type> kernel_type;
```

and then

```
kernel_type kernel1;
kernel_type kernel2;
std::vector<kernel_type> kernels;
kernels.push_back(kernel1);
kernels.push_back(kernel2);
```

So you have:

- Types

  - `kernel_type` as a typedef of `radial_basis_kernel<sample_type>`
  - `std::vector<kernel_type>`
- Objects

  - `kernel1`of type `kernel_type`
  - `kernel2`of type `kernel_type`
  - `kernels`of type `std::vector<kernel_type>`

Comment: Thanks but I would like to have different kind of kernel_type not just radial_basis_kernel (I should have mentioned that) How can I do ?

Comment: @user1595929: In what way are they supposed to differ, other than their name? In your question they don't whatsoever.

Comment: @user1595929 Sooo you need to have a container of (more or less) completely unrelated types. You can either, create a base common class (that all types to be stored derive from) and store pointers to that base common class... or I believe there are containers in boost that allows to store heterogeneous objects.